# Remove all strings with duplicates in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to implement this in Objective-C.

I want to remove the strings in an `NSArray` that have appear more than once in the array.

At the end I want to have an array that only has the unique lines in an array (meaning that not just the duplicates are deleted but also the original string that matches the duplicates.)

For example if you had the following array:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bob", @"frank", @"sarah", @"sarah", @"fred", @"corey", @"corey", nil];
```

I would want the new array to look like this:

```
@"bob", @"frank", @"fred"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use an [`NSCountedSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSCountedSet *countedSet = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:yourArray];
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[yourArray count]];

for(id obj in countedSet) {
   if([countedSet countForObject:obj] == 1) {
      [finalArray addObject:obj];
   }
}
```

[@Caleb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643383/caleb) suggested adding a method to `NSCountedSet` called `-objectsWithCount:,`, which I've implemented here:

```
@interface NSCountedSet (JRCountedSetAdditions)

- (NSArray *) objectsWithCount:(NSUInteger) count;

@end

@implementation NSCountedSet (JRCountedSetAdditions) 

- (NSArray *) objectsWithCount:(NSUInteger) count {
   NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
   for(id obj in self) {
      if([self countForObject:obj] == count) {
        [array addObject:obj];
      }  
   }
   return [array copy];
}

@end
```

Once that's done, all you need is **one line**:

```
NSArray *finalArray = [[NSCountedSet setWithArray:yourArray] objectsWithCount:1];
```

*By the way, this is type-agnostic, so this will work with any Objective-C object. :-)*

Comment: Why use an enumerator? Just use fast enumeration!

Comment: One line: `NSArray *finalArray = [[NSCountedSet setWithObjects:yourArray] allObjects];`

Comment: @Caleb: If that would work, I would've done it that way. But alas, it does not as `-allObjects` returns unique objects (i.e. *one* of the dupes), while the logic behind this is that we don't want the dupes either.

Comment: @Caleb: So, with your suggestion, the result would be: `@"frank", @"corey", @"fred", @"bob", @"sarah"`.

Comment: Hey - you edited your answer! Makes mine a little less relevant ;)

Comment: @Jacob: Gotcha. I missed the requirement to remove the duplicated string as well as the duplicates. ;-) Given that, it'd be nice to take your `for` loop and put it in a `-objectsWithCount:` method on NSCountedSet.

Answer (score 10):

One liner : `uniqueArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:duplicateArray] allObjects];` if you don't care about the ordering :D

Comment: I was here to answer that!! Happy to see my answer is already here +1!!

- (NSArray*)removeDuplicates:(NSArray*)list
{
    return [[NSSet setWithArray: list] allObjects];
}

Comment: [WARNING], Update: No longer surprised haha, after a buggy afternoon I learned the hard way, this code is not guaranteed to retain the order of your array. Use `[[NSOrderedSet ordereredSetWithArray:duplicateArray] array]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different approach from [Jacob's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375409/remove-all-strings-with-duplicates-in-nsarray-so-that-each-index-is-unique-in-the/6375561#6375561):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bob", @"frank", @"sarah", @"sarah", @"fred", @"corey", @"corey", nil];

NSCountedSet *namesSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSMutableArray *namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];

[namesSet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop){
    if ([namesSet countForObject:obj] == 1) {
        [namesArray addObject:obj];
    }
}];
```

And

```
NSLog(@"old: %@\nNew: %@", array, namesArray);
```

gives:

```
2011-06-16 18:10:32.783 SetTest[1756:903] old: (
    bob,
    frank,
    sarah,
    sarah,
    fred,
    corey,
    corey
)
New: (
    frank,
    fred,
    bob
)
```

Blocks are your friends! And since `NSCountedSet` is a subclass of `NSSet` you can use the block methods that are available there.

Comment: @Abizem: I'm sorry, how on earth is that different other than the usage of `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`?

Comment: @Abizem: And, technically speaking, it is more expensive to allocate a block on the stack than a scoped `id` reference.

Comment: It's different from your original answer that used an enumerator, and I am trying to show that blocks could also be used in this situation, and with a bit of thread safe code thrown in, this could be done concurrently.

Comment: @Abizem Looks like you have a couple of memory leaks there... ;)

Comment: Absolutely. I ran it in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`! Also, I use GC ;)

Comment: I think you do not require if block within passed block. [namesArray addObject:obj]; within block body will simply serve our purpose.

Comment: The point of the if block is to filter out entries if there are duplicates, nit just to remove the duplicates. Have a look at the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simplest approach to remove duplicate strings:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bob", @"frank", @"sarah", @"sarah", @"fred", @"corey", @"corey", nil];
NSArray *distintStrings = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```